# Concurrent Users Load test for WebSocket is not executing properly in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr

I'm doing concurrent users load test for SignalR Protocol with WebSocket transport, I'm able run the script successfully for single users with more than 1 iteration. If I run it for concurrent users I'm not getting the expected behavior- which is I'm getting Second users response in first user request.

Please guide me here.

Comment: which JMeter Plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi Amol, I'm using Peter Doornbosch's WebSocket plugin (https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

Comment: Can you please post the test plan, i used that plugin and it was working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [parameterization or correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) fails somewhere somehow, i.e. you're sending the same session argument for both users.

Use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination in order to inspect request and response details and associated [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values.